# How to add C compiler in MPLAB IDE v 8.0?

Tags: ide, firmware, mplab

I am trying to write some programs using MPLAB IDE in C language. For that I have installed version 8.0 MPLAB. But I could not find out the C compiler in it. So how to proceed to get the C compiler. Hope to get quick responses.
                  Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install a C compiler separate.  MPLAB supports several C compilers and it's easiest just to download one from Microchip.  The compiler you'll need will depend on the chip family you are looking to program against whether it be 8, 16, or 32 bit.  You can find more information on the various compilers available from Microchip [here](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en_us/devtools/mplabxc/).